# Confused with output to console, C / USB CDC / PIC18F2550

Tags: c, usb, pic, cdc

I have a problem that is probably a simple misunderstanding on my end.
I have a PIC18F2550 device with a USB CDC firmware. I would like to send it a command to output something to the console every second. However, it doesn't seem to work. I put in a loop to iterate for 5 seconds and display an output message every second, but it won't actually output anything. It passes through the 5 second loop until the end where it DOES display the final message after the loop was executed. It won't output anything DURING the loop though.

I included my entire ProcessIO function because I think it's important for this issue, but I commented where I placed the exact command I'm trying to figure out.

Thanks for any suggestions you guys have, I appreciate it. I'm a mechanical engineer trying to learn some embedded stuff.

```
/********************************************************************
* Function:        void ProcessIO(void)
* Overview:        This function is a place holder for other user
*                  routines. It is a mixture of both USB and
*                  non-USB tasks.
*******************************************************************/
void ProcessIO(void)
{
BYTE numBytesRead;

// User Application USB tasks
if((USBDeviceState < CONFIGURED_STATE)||(USBSuspendControl==1)) return;

if (USBUSARTIsTxTrfReady())
{
    if((CDCattached == 0x01) && (CDCattachedcount == 2))
    {
        putUSBUSART((char*)"Text Message\r\n",49);
        CDCTxService();
        CDCattachedcount = 0;
        CDCattached = 0x00;
    }
    numBytesRead = getsUSBUSART(USB_Out_Buffer, 64);
    if (numBytesRead == 1)
    {
        if ((USB_Out_Buffer[0] == '\r'))                      //Received ENTER? Ues-> End of Command
        {
            if (pos >0)
            {
                command_recvd = 0x01;
                Command[pos++] = '\0';
                pos = 0;
            }
        }
        else if ((USB_Out_Buffer[0] == 0x7F) || (USB_Out_Buffer[0] == 0x08))
        {
            if (pos > 0) pos--;
            Command[pos] = '\0';
            putUSBUSART ((char*) USB_Out_Buffer, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            Command[pos++] = USB_Out_Buffer[0];
            putUSBUSART((char*) USB_Out_Buffer, 1);
            Command[pos]='\0';
        }       //No:- Store Character to String
    }
    else if ((numBytesRead > 1))
    {
        strncpy(Command,USB_Out_Buffer,numBytesRead);
        for(int indx = numBytesRead; indx < 64; indx++)
        {
            Command[indx]='\0';
        }
        pos = numBytesRead--;
        command_recvd = 0x01;
        Command[pos++] = '\0';
        // putUSBUSART((char*) USB_Out_Buffer, 1);
        pos = 0;
    }

    if (command_recvd == 0x01)
    {
        for (int aaa = 0; aaa <= 63; aaa++)
        {
            output_message[aaa]= '\0';
        }


************** THIS IS WHERE MY TEST COMMAND IS ***************

        if (strnicmp((char*) Command, (char*) "test", 4) == 0)
        {
            sprintf(output_message, "\r\nStarting loop...\r\n");
            for int bbb = 0; bbb < 5; bbb++)
            {
                sprintf(output_message, "\r\nLooping...\r\n");
                for (delayIndex = 0; delayIndex < 1000; delayIndex++)
                {
                     __delay_ms(1);
                }
            }
            sprintf(output_message, "\r\nLoop finished!\r\n");
        }
        else
        {
            invalidCommand:
            sprintf(output_message, "\r\nInvalid Command Received. Please Retry.\r\n\0");
        }
        command_recvd = 0x00;
    }
}
CDCTxService();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `putUSBUSART()` and `CDCTxService()` before overwriting `output_message`
Also, `CDCTxService()` needs to be called frequently, so you have to call it during the delay loop.

```
        for int bbb = 0; bbb < 5; bbb++)
        {
            sprintf(output_message, "\r\nLooping...\r\n");
            putsUSBUSART(output_message);

            for (delayIndex = 0; delayIndex < 1000; delayIndex++)
            {
                 __delay_ms(1); 

                 if(USBUSARTIsTxTrfReady()) {
                      sprintf(output_message, "\r\nInside inner loop\r\n");
                      putsUSBUSART(output_message);
                 }
                 CDCTxService();
            }
        }
```

Although that kind of bloking delays could work ( `__delay_ms()` ), a better aproach is to check for an ellapsed timer, or a timestamp. Something like:

```
        for int bbb = 0; bbb < 5; bbb++)
        {
            sprintf(output_message, "\r\nLooping...\r\n");
            putsUSBUSART(output_message);

            timestamp = TickGet(); 
            while (TickDiff(timestamp, TickGet()) < TICK_SECOND)
            {
                 if(USBUSARTIsTxTrfReady()) {
                      sprintf(output_message, "\r\nInside inner loop\r\n");
                      putsUSBUSART(output_message);
                 }
                 CDCTxService();
            }
        }
```

TickGet and TickDiff are functions you have to implement yourself, however there are lots of examples on Microchip libraries

Comment: That definitely works, thanks Smasho. Are there any disadvantages to calling CDCTxService() so often? 

Also, theoretically, is it possible to put an sprintf() inside the delay loop? I tried it but got some weird results. Can putUSBUSART() not function as fast as 1ms?

Comment: CDCTxService() does the actual sending of the data that you enqueue with putsUSBUSART. There ir no problem on calling it as often as you want, but you do need to wait for the transmission to be completed before sending more data. Thats why you can't call putUSBUSART inside a loop without enough delay. You must check for USBUSARTIsTxTrfReady() before you send more data.

Comment: Smasho, you are awesome! Out of curiosity, what makes your TickDiff method superior to __delay_ms()?  I think because delay_ms is dependent on the oscillator and perhaps isn't always perfectly accurate? Thanks!

Comment: The main issue is not accuracy, both methods end up depending on the oscillator. The difference is on the programming model. `__delay_ms()`, function takes total control of the CPU, so you can't do anything during the delay (unless you work with interrupts).

Comment: Consider the difference if you call `__delay_ms(1000)`. During that second, USB stop processing events, and input buffers could overflow. Of course, if you just make small delays like in the example, you can process events between `__delay_ms()` calls, but the total delay is the one of `__delay_ms()`  **plus** the delay of your process, which is pretty difficult to know, and thats when you loose precision.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: this approach won't work. You'll need to rethink how you're doing this.

USB devices **cannot** delay while processing events — they must be able to respond promptly to every request sent from the host. Delaying for as long as a second will typically cause the host to assume the device has been disconnected.

It's critical to understand here that the USB device model is based (almost) entirely around the host sending requests to a device, and the device replying. Devices cannot generate unsolicited responses.

Now, the reason you're not seeing the expected results here is because `sprintf()` doesn't send the results to the host; all it does is put a message into a buffer to *prepare* it to be sent back. Calling it multiple times overwrites that buffer, rather than sending multiple messages back.

Comment: I agree, but microchip libraries generaly works having "task" functions, that you call periodically in order to make the work, repond to events, and so on. You can call them every 1 us, or every 10 ms, those functions have they own way of accounting time. So that allows you to make a delay and continue event processing, as far as you keep calling the "task" function.

Comment: Thanks duskwuff! Would you be able to point me towards a different approach to this?